# How to run CSOM function on Linux server?

Tags: csom

I create some CSOM function by Visual studio 2015 and want to run in Linux server. How to do it?

Comment: CSOM is written in C# code (.Net framework) and will not execute on Linux

Comment: Robert, .NET framework is available on Linux through Mono project. It has been around for a while now and it is a Microsoft-supported open source implementation of .NET. And the official .NET framework is going open source, so if not yet, it will be available on Linux.

Comment: True, but I'm not convinced that all dependencies that CSOM needs are implemented in Mono?  @PaulStrupeikis, or am I just to sceptical? ;)

Comment: @RobertLindgren One should be, but it may just work: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/

Answer (score 0):

Back in 2013 Stephane Cordonnier posted [Possible to use .NET 4.0 assembly with Xamarin.iOS and Mono 3.0.x ?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3296/possible-to-use-net-4-0-assembly-with-xamarin-ios-and-mono-3-0-x) with the error message as follows:

> It's an assembly created by Microsoft (SharePoint 2013 Client Side
>   Object Model) and **it requires .NET 4.0 to work**.
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585
>
> When I try to use it on my Xamarin.iOS project, I receive the
>   following error :

```
Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type System.Uri [System,
Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]' to
System.Uri [System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]'
```

Since then, the [Mono Project have evolved and do support .NET 4.5](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/):

> The easiest way to describe what Mono currently supports is:
>   **Everything in .NET 4.5** except WPF, WWF, and **with limited WCF** and
>   limited ASP.NET 4.5 async stack.

And CSOM uses WCF as stated in [Using the Client Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx)

> The CSOM uses a set of specialized Windows Communication Foundation
>   (WCF) services to communicate with the SharePoint server

The only way to know is to test, so download the Mono Project on your Linux instance and give it a try. It really depends on which part of WCF the Mono Project have implemented. I'm sure It'll work if not today, but in the near future...

Comment: the license is here http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=280198 says that its not allowed. Distirbuted for windows only